# Accomplish this foreach task with a built-in PHP array function

Tags: php, arrays, refactoring

How can we accomplish this foreach task with a built-in PHP array function?

```
$requestProducts = $this->request['products'];

$products = [];

foreach ($requestProducts as $product) {
    if (!empty($product['search']['value'])) {
        array_push($products, [
            'name' => $product['name'],
            'title' => $product['title'],
            'search' => $product['search']['value']
        ]);
    }
}
```

Something in this way I would like to have but without null values.

```
$requestProducts = $this->request['products'];

$products = array_map(function ($product) {
    if (!empty($product['search']['value'])) {
        return [
            'name' => $product['name'],
            'title' => $product['title'],
            'search' => $product['search']['value']
        ];
    }
    return null; // without null
}, $requestProducts);

$products = array_filter($products) // without this
```

The task should look encapsulated.

Comment: `foreach` approach is good enough for your case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution with [`array_reduce`](http://php.net/array_reduce):

```
$requestProducts = $this->request['products'];

$products = array_reduce(
    // your values
    $requestProducts,                   
    // reducing function
    function ($t, $product) {
        if (!empty($product['search']['value'])) {
            $t[] = [
                'name' => $product['name'],
                'title' => $product['title'],
                'search' => $product['search']['value']
            ];
        }

        return $t;
    }, 
    // initial value for reduced items
    []
);
```